# JBoss error: org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation with mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss

I'm creating a barebones project from an example a tutor gave me to run on WildFly. Whenever I run the server I get the error:

`[org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar")]) - failure description: "WFLYSRV0137: No deployment content with hash 3ab47e0f358f83fa29c2b3ba8106c0cc016e1198 is available in the deployment content repository for deployment 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar'. This is a fatal boot error. To correct the problem, either restart with the --admin-only switch set and use the CLI to install the missing content or remove it from the configuration, or remove the deployment from the xml configuration file and restart."`

My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>BrassDucks</groupId>
    <artifactId>BrassDucks</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Brass Ducks</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-m01</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/ejb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And while I don't think these are relevant my `ApplicationConfig.java`:

```
package brass.ducks.application;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/") 
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {}
```

and my `Controller.java` looks like this:

```
package brass.ducks.controller;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Controller {
    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Controller.class);



    @GET
    @Path("hello")
    public String listStaff() {
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

How do I remedy this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe are getting some sort of version conflict on the mysql driver.

Ideally, you should install and use the correct version of the mysql driver as a module. You can install it using the maven plugin or create a module manually:

- http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/maven-tutorials/jboss-maven/configuring-maven-wildfly-plugin
- https://developer.jboss.org/thread/271155
- https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/examples/add-resource-example.html
- https://javavolker.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/automated-jdbc-driver-and-datasource-deployment-with-wildfly-8/

Once the version of the mysql driver in your pom.xml and the one configured in wildfly are consistent, your error should go away.